# There is sorted set functionality in tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

I'm starting work on project which will require to do many work with sorted sets. I need to keep some sets sorted and do CRUDs as fast as possible, there is any tarantool functionality that allows to insert data to sorted set like redis ZADD function? Or i have to sort data on my own (using C or lua scripts) or maybe sorted selects from tarantool is fast enough? Please give me some opinions or advices

Answer (score 2):

In Tarantool, TREE index automatically sorts your data. Create a simple space with TREE primary key on the first field. You can store any json data in the second or third, fourth, ... field, or you can then format the space to reflect your schema and set values will conform to the schema, just like in a relational database.

Comment: Could you reccomend me solution in that case: I have some tuples that have unique_id, and kind (which is integer and there can be milions kinds), i need to fast store and select data ordered by kind value and id respectivetely. So if i create unique TREE index for kinds and store sorted arrays of id's that will be ok? Or maybe is some faster way? Or maybe sorting with two field is fast enough?